# .innerHTML (with Ajax) not showing results in the webpage

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am trying to do a web app that shows results from a query, using Google Books API. 
My code is working, but the .innerHTML is not showing any result on the Html page. This is the Html that I am using.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- -->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Google Books API Search</title>

        <!--linkink stylesheet-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">


    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="search" class="#f5f5f5 grey lighten-4 z-depth-5">
             <form id="bookForm">
                <div class="inputField">
                <input type="search" id="books">
                <label for="search">Search for books</label>
                </div> 
                 <div class="btnHolder">
                     <button id="button" class="btn red">Search</button>
                 </div> 
            </form>
        </div>

        <div id="results">


        </div>

        <!--linking scripts-->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and this is the JavaScript code that is running.

```
/*global document, $, console, event, results */

function bookSearch() {
    /* eslint-disable no-console */
    event.preventDefault();                      //preventing auto refresh of the page
    //console.log("This function is working.");  //console.log to see if the function was running properly

    var search = document.getElementById('search').value; //storing the value of search
    document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = '';
    console.log(search);

    $.ajax({

        url: "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=" + search, //linking API + our search
        dataType: "json",

        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data)
            for (i=0;i<data.items.lenght;i++){
                results.innerHTML = "<h2>" + data.items[i].volumeInfo.title + "</h2>"
            }
        },

    type: "GET"

    })

}
```

From the console, I can see that data are gathered in the right way to the API, but the main problem is that I can not manage to show the results on the page itself. 
Maybe it is just a silly mistake, but I am struggling to find a solution for this.

Comment: You have a typo in the for loop. Should be .length

Comment: also your variable "results" for "results.innerHTML" seems undefined ?

Comment: Was about to say you don't seem to declare your results variable. You should declare it such as var results = document.getElementbyId('results');

Comment: And when you get the typo fixed, That is going to overwrite on every iteration: `results.innerHTML = "<h2>" + data.items[i].volumeInfo.title + "</h2>"` You are only ever going to see the last one.

Comment: Oh god, you are right. I am using Brackets and I thought that I autocompleted .length in the right way.

Comment: Also as mentioned above you need to append to the html in the for loop rather than overwriting it each time

Comment: I noticed that is going to overwrite on every iteration. How can I avoid this? Because now I can see an output on the Html webpage. Showing just one result.

Comment: build a string....

Comment: you could use the appendChild() method. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp

Comment: I managed to show every result in changing "results.innerHTML = " with "results.innerHTML +=".

Thanks so much to everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want write multiple result, one after other, but you override the 'results' content. One fix can be this:

```
success: function (data) {
  for (let i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++ ) {
    results.innerHTML += '<h2>'+ data.items[i].volumeInfo.title +'</h2>';
    // ^ defined      ^ see the plus sing in the declaration
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not retrieving the DOM element `results` and assigning the `innerHTML`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=" + search, //linking API + our search
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data)
        // ADD THIS LINE
        var results = document.getElementById('results');
        for (i=0;i<data.items.length;i++){ // YOU HAD A TYPO HERE WITH `length`
            // YOU WANT TO CONCATENATE CONTENT OTHERWISE YOU'LL REPLACE IT EACH TIME
            results.innerHTML += "<h2>" + data.items[i].volumeInfo.title + "</h2>"
        }
    },
    type: "GET"
})
```

Its definitely recommended to update the DOM the minimal amount possible, so it would be better to create and assign a variable, then assign `results.innerHTML` ONCE.  But this should get you started.